# Jquery check if image has a title attribute

Tags: jquery, if-statement, attributes, image, title

How to check if an img tag has a title attribute?

Like in this Pseudo code:

```
IF image has a tile attribute THEN 

DO Something
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just do:

```
if ($('#selection').attr('title')){
alert('YAY 4 TITLES');
}
```

Comment: damn you, beat me by 5 seconds!

Answer (score 2):

> if **an** img tag has a title attribute?

give your `img` tag an id

```
if($("#imgID").is("[title]")){
 //your code here
}
```

to select `img` tags out of all `img` tags that has the *title* `attr` you can use
the code below will filter out all the img tags that has an attr title and hides them, you can modify according to your need

```
$("img").filter(function(){return $(this).is("[title]")}).hide();
```

Comment: Or, you could just write `$("img[title]").hide();`

Answer (score 1):

Like this my friend:

```
if($('element').attr('title')){
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($("img").attr("title")){
    // do something
}
```

this will do it :)

I love it at SO when some simply question is asked all the answers are rushing in :D

Answer (score 0):

```
var img = $("#idOfYourImage");
alert(img.is("[title]");
```

Hope it helped :)

You can also just include the `[title]` attribute when searching for the image.

```
alert($("#idOfYourImage[title]").length > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('#img').attr('title') !== undefined) {
    // attribute exists
} else {
    // attribute does not exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("#imgID").attr("title")==undefined || $("#imgID").attr("title")!=""){

Do Something

}
```